# How to fix bootstrap dropdown fails when carousel is added?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I used bootstrap default nav-bar and  carousel in a single page,
they work correctly if placed in different pages.
when i included both in same page dropdown no longer drops down the menu.
however, carousel is working fine.
these both needs to be in same page.
how do i fix this?

Comment: Please write code what have you tried.

Answer (score 1):

1. First check bootstrap css
2. Then apply css related class for nav-bar
3. check that which javascript / jQuery conflict

Comment: That answered it.